# Trying to sum up the grandTotal doesn't work

Tags: angular

I narrowed down my problem to the quantity buttons submitting every time they're clicked so I deleted all of my previous code and now I am just showing the quantity button code.

The HTML

```
<button class="minus-btn" (click)="minus(product)" type="button" name="btn" onclick="return false;">
<img src="../assets/images/minus.svg" alt="minus" /></button>
<input class="num" name="int" [value]="product.nullValue" formControlName="int" ng-minlength="0" type="number" required />
<button class="plus-btn" (click)="plus($event, product)" name="btn" type="button" onclick="return false;">
<img src="../assets/images/plus.svg" alt="plus" /></button>
```

and in the controller:

```
plus($event, product:any) {
  $event.preventDefault();
  product.nullValue++;
  this.quantity = product.nullValue;
  console.log('click submitted');
  return false;  
  return this.quantity;
 
}

minus(product:any){ 
 product.nullValue--;
  this.quantity = product.nullValue;
  console.log('click submitted'); 
  return false;
  return this.quantity;

}
```

Comment: Ciao, of course you already checked [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/)...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call that grandTotal function after the lifecycle of ngAfterViewInit(). It may resolve your issue.

Create one variable in your component.

```
let grandTotal: number;
```

and assign the value in `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.total_price = this.quantity * this.product_price;
  this.sum += this.total_price;
  this.grandTotal = this.sum;
}
```

pipe for your calculation

```
@Pipe({name: 'grandtotal'})
export class GrandTotalPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(product_price: number, quantity: number) {
   return product_price * quantity; 
 }
}
```

Your HTML template like this:

```
<div>Grand Total {{item.product_price | grandtotal:  item.quantity}}</div>
```

Comment: I added ngAfterViewInit() but now nothing displays for grandTotal. Thanks Arunkumar Ramasamy for your effort.

Comment: And when I do  console.log("test" + this.grandTotal); in the ngAfterViewInit() function, I get NaN.

Comment: Is you print the value of the this.quantity, this.product_price and this.sum in console

Comment: console.log("test quantity " + this.quantity);
console.log("test price " + this.product_price);
console.log("test grandTotal " + this.grandTotal);
The results of the console.log:
quantity undefined
test price undefined
test grandTotal NaN

Comment: I am looping through the ngFor directive so the quantity and price get summed up repeatedly. But when I take the function out of the for loop it doesn't have any access to the price and quantity variables.

Comment: may you need to create a pipe and then you will do some calculation over there after that calculation you can return the value which you need to show in your template.

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: When I take grandTotal out of the ngFor loop it does access the price and quantity variables after all but I am still getting wild values.

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz.com. It may better to find out the issue.

Comment: I created a custom pipe but I am getting the same kind of values that I got when I used a getter.

Comment: I edited my question to show the pipe that I'm now using.

Comment: I can't publish to stackblitz because I have too many modules that aren't there. For example, I am using firebase and they don't have that.

Comment: The problem is that the price and quantity are getting submitted twice. Once when the quantity is increased or decreased and then again when the Add to Cart button calls the onSubmit function.

Comment: I edited my question to show what the quantity buttons do.

Comment: Updated in my comment @MaureenMoore. Please check it once.

Comment: return product_price * quantity; in the pipe doesn't return the grand total just the subtotal. Thanks Arunkumar Ramasamy for trying to help.

Comment: The quantity buttons are submitting the quantity every time I click on the plus or minus image. I checked it in console.log. How can I prevent the buttons from submitting?

Comment: I changed the buttons to anchors but it's still submitting via the click function.

Comment: When I add a disabled for invalid form function to the quantity buttons and then add required to the text input field, it disables the buttons when I click on them.

Comment: I added onclick="return false;" to the quantity buttons but they're still submitting when I click on them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218219/discussion-between-arunkumar-ramasamy-and-maureen-moore).